# Windows Service with running some Process

Tags: winforms, windows-services, process.start

I have a problem with windows service. I'd like to his level run the program in a given situation. Every minute check a certain value and if the value is to adopt "truth" is to me the program starts. Only at the moment this does not work ...

The problem is that when debugging the code executes correctly, it displays my window, but the service is run normally nothing happens ...

Link to movies about this all:
https://youtu.be/GPv5dn92BGg

Comment: Did you configure the service to allow desktop interaction? Running processeses from a service with desktop interaction I not common practice and only supported for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Hmm, probably not, I do not even know that you need to do something like that. I want ws checking every X time data items in the database and, if necessary, to run a winform with the message (currently running is just an example)

Comment: I marked this option, but it did not help

http://screenshooter.net/102681996/daxmkbc

Comment: Class helped here: https://github.com/murrayju/CreateProcessAsUser

Answer (score 0):

You need to jump through several hoops to launch interactive applications from a service. First, the service needs to be explicitly allowed to interact with the desktop. Then the service needs to specify the correct WindowStation for it to show on.

It may be simpler to just set your child application up as a scheduled task, as these can interact with the desktop for you

Comment: hmmm, and you could direct me ?? :) I have not used yet tasks. On the sites I work recently and just get to know them, and I wanted to create such a thing, that the program would operate in the background and check every minute given value, and if you run another application with a message I used this but this not works  http://screenshooter.net/102681996/wdghxnr   thread

Comment: And im trying use "Task" like here and too is nothing happend normly http://screenshooter.net/102681996/ewvvgfl but in debug is ok..

Comment: I marked this option, but it did not help

http://screenshooter.net/102681996/daxmkbc

Comment: For the record, the "allow service to interact with desktop" option only allows the service to use the legacy support for interactive services, which is disabled by default (and inconvenient to use even when enabled).  Instead, you can use CreateProcessAsUser (or one of the other CreateProcessXxx functions) to launch an interactive application directly into the user's session.  There are a number of existing questions covering this.  But I agree this isn't the best approach for the OPs problem.

Comment: (I don't think you even need to use a scheduled task.  A simple background application, configured to launch automatically when the user logs in, should be perfect.)

Comment: This option is a difficult for me, because would be running the application in the background all the time and the application would have to be on the taskbar or as a thumbnail next to watch. And I would get such a thing, that I was checking something in the database every minute and if it is true it runs my program from the folder (the display shows the user etc.). This program will be mainly know about throwing a file to the site either has to alert the user to launch the stream. I solved the problem with the class / method from this address: https://github.com/murrayju/CreateProcessAsUser :